# Quickbooks Web Connector - Version 2.1.0.30

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I would like to know If there's anyone who has the link to Quickbooks Web Connector - Version 2.1.0.30, as It's not available on the website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/01_quickbooks_desktop/1_get_started/99_get_started_with_quickbooks_web_connector

It will be towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks @William Lorfing. Im aware of this link. Unfortunately, that version doesn't seem to be accessible. Do you have any alternative?